# skipping of several line and start reading only numbers

Tags: matlab

let us suppose we have following  table

```
% El-Centro earthquake signal:
% North-south component recorded at Imperial Valley Irrigation District
% substation in El Centro, California, during the Imperial Valley,
% California earthquake of May, 18, 1940. The magnitude is 7.1. and the maximum ground acceleration is 0.3495g
%
%   Time (sec)      Acceleration (g)    
   0.0000000e+00   1.1000000e-03
   2.0000000e-02   1.1000000e-03
   4.0000000e-02   1.3000000e-03
   6.0000000e-02   1.4000000e-03
   8.0000000e-02   1.3000000e-03
   1.0000000e-01   1.2000000e-03
```

it is just fragment, i would like to create  two dimensional table, one for time and second for  acceleration,first of all we should skip text lines,  i have tried following command

```
M = dlmread('ELCENTRO.txt', ' ', 6, 0);
```

that means i have   skipped 6 row, but  after i got matrix with dimension of

```
size(M)

ans =

        2829           7
```

based on result i have   done another command

```
M = dlmread('ELCENTRO.txt', ' ', 6, 3);
```

and now dimension of M  changed

```
size(M)

ans =

        2829           4
```

now i can do following  thing

```
 M(:,2:3)=[];
```

now M  contains two column, one for time  and second for signal, but  how can i do this using dlmread command? thanks in advance

Comment: Are you going to keep this question up this time or just keep deleting it when it garners negative feedback?

Comment: i have asked  now  question in good format, so i need just answer

Comment: There's an [edit] button for a reason.

Comment: @excaza on the previous question, i  just got negative feedback for no reason, that why i have delete those  and created new  one

Comment: Except you received feedback in the comments of both posts. Deleting questions to dodge negative reputation is very much against the rules of the site. As a user with close to 6k reputation you should know this.

Comment: @excaza we sometimes  have such kind of  phrase : if  baby is ok then it does not matter other things, so  let forget about this  and prepare for new year .happy new year in advance

Comment: As I commented in both previous questions, per [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html), `dlmread` treats repeated whitespace as a single delimiter and you can specify row and column offsets without specifying a delimiter by using an empty character array as a placeholder. So `M = dlmread('ELCENTRO.txt', '', 6, 0);` returns the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dmlread` is a pretty old function with few bells and whistles.  It appears that it won't work for your file as you have a 2 character delimiter (i.e. two spaces between the numbers).

But even if it did work, you're better off using tables for this type of data.

```
tbl = readtable('ELCENTRO.txt','HeaderLines',6,'ReadVariableNames',false,'Format','%f  %f')
```

You then want to change the column names,

```
tbl.Properties.VariableNames = {'Time','Acceleration'}
```

In many cases the names could be read from the file, but the format of your file precludes that.

If you're not used to using tables then see the following as a starting point on how to manipulate them,

```
docsearch('Access Data in a Table')
```

In particular, if you do really just want the data as a matrix then do,

```
M = tbl{:,:}
```

Comment: aaa  that is great answer,  so in most of case, this function will work right?

Comment: It is often a good option for text and Excel files, but whether it works or not will depend on the format of the specific file being read.

Comment: except  readtable, what are most  frequently used file reading functions?

Comment: It's also worth noting that `M = dlmread('ELCENTRO.txt', '', 6, 0);` returns the desired result by allowing MATLAB to collapse repeated whitespace into one delimiter rather than treating `' '` as the delimiter, adding extra columns.